# Execute OAuth2 with the Mailchimp API in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mailchimp

I've been following MailChimp's OAuth2 tutorial (https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/how-to-use-oauth2/) but got stuck when making a post request with the code and secret/key params. The closest I've gotten is a 400 Bad Request response. My code:

```
var args = {
headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
body: "grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=" + client_id + "&client_secret=" + client_secret + "&redirect_uri=" + encoded_url + "&code=" + req.query.code,
url: "https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/token"
};
var r = request.post(args, function(err, req, body){
  console.log(err)
  console.log(req)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I was running in to the same thing, and finally found it.  My code was very similar to yours:

```
this.globals.request({
        method: "POST",
        uri: "https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/token",
        form:  {
            grant_type: "authorization_code",
            client_id: this.globals.mailchimp_client_id,
            client_secret: this.globals.mailchimp_client_secret,
            redirect_uri: encodeURIComponent(fullUrl),
            code: req.query.code
        }
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
            self.globals.logger.debug(self.moduleName, "getMailchimpToken", "Error " + response.statusCode + "(" + response.statusMessage + ") from mailchimp: " + error, true);
            body = {};
        }
        self.globals.logger.debug(self.moduleName, "getMailchimpToken", "got body: " + JSON.stringify(body), false);
        deferred.resolve(body);
});
```

The problem here, and I suspect with yours, is that you are using an encoded URL in the form data, but request will encode it again.  When I looked at the querystring, I saw things like

```
&redirect_uri=http%253A%252F%252F
```

where the %s were being re-encoded.  Changed `encodeURIComponent(fullUrl),` to just `fullUrl`, and it worked.

One important note that was not clear to me - the redirect_uri should be the same one used in the OAuth call, *including the path*.  Note that per the Mailchimp docs, you can vary the path in the actual call from the redirect_url used when registering the app, which is where this can be important.

Comment: It's amazing they have so many integrations even with such a crappy documentation